# How to disableVisual Studio debugger for just one application

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I am currently working on an VB.net program that handles an object defined in a COM dll.
The problem is that sometimes that object causes a crash: an exception that cannot be handled with a 'Try Catch' is thrown and a dialog asking to debug with Visual Studio appears.
I would like to disable this dialog **only** on this application.
All the other .Net applications should display this dialog in case of crash.
By the way,I use visual Studio 2008.

Comment: Start by subscribing the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event.  This might still not catch the exception if the error occurs in a native thread started by the COM server.  You'd then need to write native code, SetUnhandledExceptionFilter().  Quite hard to get right btw, best avoided.  Fwiw, this dialog won't offer the debugger option on your customer's machine.

Comment: Thanks, Hans. The subscription to AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event was already implemented and it doesn't work in this case. I must admit writing native code wouldn't please me: I don't really get how to implement this in my case. My experience in .Net is poor and my experience in C/C++ is worse.

Comment: I gave up the suggestion of Hans because, as he wrote, this would require writing native code and would be a bit overkill. I tried to call the Win32 API function SetUnhandledExceptionFilter() in my VB code but it didn't work (even though a my C++ test program worked fine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally chosed another approach than Hans' one (see comment): configuring the registry in order to use a custom program as debugger instead of the debugger. That program (let's call it "DebuggerCaller.exe") then redirects to Dr Watson (or any other registered debugger) or silently creates a dumpfile or a log following the name of the process that crashed.

**In the case of a managed application**

You need the set in the registry

```
KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework\DbgJITDebugLaunchSetting = 2
```

This makes the application defined in the registry at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft.NETFramework\DbgManagedDebugger to be called in case of crash. It might not be present or be equals to 16 (default).
In a machine where Visual Studio and its jit debugger is installed, the value is:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework\DbgManagedDebugger 
= "c:\WINDOWS\system32\vsjitdebugger.exe" PID %d APPDOM %d EXTEXT "%s" EVTHDL %d
```

and should be replaced by something like

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework\DbgManagedDebugger 
= "MyDebugCaller.exe"  PID %d APPDOM %d EXTEXT "%s" EVTHDL %d
```

Else, the entry may not exist or be

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework\DbgManagedDebugger 
= "drwtsn32.exe" -p %ld -e %ld
```

should be replaced by something like

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework\DbgManagedDebugger 
= "*MyDebugCaller.exe*"  -p %ld -e %ld
```

Please note that the arguments remain unchanged, that way our debuugger can use them (especially the PID) to determine the process name, create logs and forward to another debugger if required.

**In the case of a native application**

The procedure is very similar.
First set

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug\Auto 
= 1
```

The entry key the debugger of native applications is defined is

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug\Debugger
```

Its value is generally `drwtsn32.exe" -p %ld -e %ld`or `"c:\WINDOWS\system32\vsjitdebugger.exe" -p %ld -e %ld` if Visual Studio is installed.
It should be changed into sth like this:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug\Debugger 
= "*MyDebugCaller.exe*" -p %ld -e %ld
```

I hope this was clear.
You can have info on jit debugger settings at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ac5yxx6%28v=vs.90%29.aspx